# Hg clone fails with "Cannot connect to X server"

Tags: linux, version-control, mercurial, xserver

On a machine where I have only SSH access, `hg clone` suddenly fails:

```
hg clone http://cls@<repopath>
: cannot connect to X server
```

Why is X server involved at all? How can I fix this?

Comment: Check that `hg` is really the mercurial executable by executing `which hg`.

Comment: @Axel `hg` is really mercurial. `hg pull` works by the way.

Comment: try adding --verbose and --traceback to see what additional info comes out.

Comment: @Ry4an When calling `hg clone --verbose http://cls@<repopath>` everything works fine. I'm confused.

Comment: `--verbose` definitely won't change the behavior, so unless you can still get the error without `--versbose` I think you had a transient failure of the sort the internet is famous for.

Comment: @Ry4an I can still get the error without `--verbose`, nothing transient.

Comment: Perhaps there's a clue in `<repopath>`? I'd suspect shell expansion of something, but then why would `--verbose` make a difference? Quite a puzzle. But try enclosing the URL in single quotes anyway.

Comment: @alexis `<repopath>` is just my "anonymization" for Stackoverflow of an actual path, which is not public so nobody can try cloning this. It is not a shell expansion.

Comment: I realize that, I was just speculating that there might be something there that's responsible; if it's all letters and dots, never mind.